# Add isolate element after another in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i add some element after base element with diffrent ngModels, any change to one input affect all input (ng-models are diffrent)!!!

how can i fix it.

actually i make a html string and compile it and then use .after to add element.

but when i add 2 or more elements any change affect all of them.

controller:

```
   function makeElement() {
        var idName = "level" + vm.currentLevel + "";
        var idCss = "#" + idName + "";
        if (angular.element(idCss).length) {
            angular.element(idCss).remove();
        }

        setTimeout('', 1000);
        console.log("getChildren", vm);

        var htmlStr = angular.element(

            '<div id="'+ idName +'" class="row"> ' + 
                '<div class="col-xs-8"> ' + 
                    '<label class="vertical">{{vm.dataLevel[vm.currentLevel].Title}}</label> ' +
                    '<input type="text" id="level-' + vm.currentLevel + '-code" class="k-textbox quarter-width ltr" value="{{vm.dataLevel[vm.currentLevel].item.Code}}" disabled /> ' +
                    '<select id="data-level-' + vm.currentLevel + '" class="three-quarter-width" ng-hide="vm.isBusy" ' +
                            'kendo-drop-down-list '  +
                            'k-options="vm.dataLevel[vm.currentLevel]" ' +
                            'k-rebind ="vm.dataLevel[vm.currentLevel]"></select> ' +
                    '<span ng-show="vm.isBusy"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span> ' + 
                '</div> ' + 
                '<div class="col-xs-4 align-left" ng-show="!vm.isBusy"> ' +
                    '<label class="vertical transparent">1</label> ' + 
                    '<a kendo-button ng-click="vm.openActionDialog(1,0)"> ' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> ' + 
                    '</a> ' +
                    '<a kendo-button data-ng-disabled="!vm.dataLevel[vm.currentLevel].item.Code" ng-click="vm.openActionDialog(2,0,vm.currentLevel0Item)"> ' +
                        '<i class=" fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> ' +
                    '</a> ' +
                    '<a kendo-button data-ng-disabled="!vm.dataLevel[vm.currentLevel].item.Code" ng-click="vm.openActionDialog(3,0,vm.currentLevel0Item)"> ' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i> ' +
                    '</a> ' +
                    '<a kendo-button ng-click="vm.getData(0,0,true)"> ' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-fw"></i> ' +
                    '</a> ' +
                '</div> ' +
            '</div> <br />');

        return $compile(htmlStr)($scope);
    }
```

Comment: Bind them to different ngModels.

Comment: i have done it before but it was not working.

Comment: Then you probably did it wrong. Anyway, without code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: there is the function that make element. and in other place i get the last element with angular.element and add this to it. but the data bind to all instances. that means i have multiple elements with diffrence ngmodel but they have same data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem my mistake was using index for data as string. i wrote before:

```
'k-options="vm.dataLevel[vm.currentLevel]" '
```

but now my code is:

```
'k-options="vm.dataLevel[' + vm.currentLevel + ']" '
```